# My website is crashing due to this error Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)

Tags: mysql, crash

I am facing this error continuously once in a week.

> "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)"

How can I fixed this problem?

Please Help me.

My server is on digitalOcean host  and My webapp is in PHP.

When I run this command

> root@Sharebulk:/var/log/mysql# tail -n 50 error.log

It was showing:

```
                150515 11:54:24 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './photo_editor/fbpage_status_like' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
                150515 11:54:24 [Warning] Checking table:   './photo_editor/fbpage_status_like'
                150515 11:54:24 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './photo_editor/fbpages' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
                150515 11:54:24 [Warning] Checking table:   './photo_editor/fbpages'
                150515 11:54:24 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './photo_editor/social_fbstatus_foto' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
                150515 11:54:24 [Warning] Checking table:   './photo_editor/social_fbstatus_foto'
                150515 11:54:24 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './photo_editor/social_fbuser_info' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
                150515 11:54:24 [Warning] Checking table:   './photo_editor/social_fbuser_info'
                150515 11:54:24 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './photo_editor/social_page_status' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
                150515 11:54:24 [Warning] Checking table:   './photo_editor/social_page_status'
                150515 11:54:24 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './photo_editor/social_twitter_status' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
                150515 11:54:24 [Warning] Checking table:   './photo_editor/social_twitter_status'
                150515 11:54:24 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './photo_editor/social_twtstatus_foto' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
                150515 11:54:24 [Warning] Checking table:   './photo_editor/social_twtstatus_foto'
                150515 11:54:24 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './photo_editor/twitter_users_info' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
                150515 11:54:24 [Warning] Checking table:   './photo_editor/twitter_users_info'
                150515 12:10:44 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
                150515 12:10:44 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
                150515 12:10:44 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
                150515 12:10:44 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
                150515 12:10:44 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
                150515 12:10:44 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
                150515 12:10:44 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
                InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12
                150515 12:10:44 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
                150515 12:10:44 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
                150515 12:10:44 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
                150515 12:10:44 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
                150515 12:10:44 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
                150515 12:10:44 [ERROR] Aborting

                150515 12:10:44 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

                150515 12:10:45 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
                150515 12:10:45 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
                150515 12:10:45 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
                150515 12:10:45 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
                150515 12:10:45 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
                150515 12:10:45 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
                150515 12:10:45 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
                InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12
                150515 12:10:45 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
                150515 12:10:45 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
                150515 12:10:45 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
                150515 12:10:45 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
                150515 12:10:45 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
                150515 12:10:45 [ERROR] Aborting

                150515 12:10:45 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

                root@Sharebulk:/var/log/mysql#
```

Comment: It complains about several things. Some tables needs to be repaired or physically removed, or restored. Are you using InnoDB or MyISAM?

Comment: Also, what is your value in the config file for `innodb_force_recovery` and `myisam-recover`

Comment: All table are MyISAM ,but at last it shows:-                                             19 tables InnoDB                                                                                                                           Why it shows InnoDB  at sum and MyISAM to individual tables.Also hox can i repair tables?   config fie,i don't have,is it on server side?